# Spontaneous parametric down-conversion

Tags: quantum-cryptography, quantum-computing

we generate heralded single pho- tons via spontaneous parametric downconversion using a 5 mm long periodically-poled potassium titanyl phosphate (ppKTP) crystal pumped with a 405 nm diode laser (200 mW). The photon pairs (signal λs = 775 nm and idler λi = 850 nm) are separated via a dichroic mirror, coupled to different single-mode fibers (SMFs). The signal and idler are obey the conversation of energy such that,

```
omega_p= omega_s+omega_i        (1)
```

I did not understand ? can some help me with this part ? how  is omega_405= omega_775+omega_850?

Comment: I've got the strong idea that a physics or quantum specific site would be the best place, this is not a site where we do often have questions such as these. Actually, this is the first one I've seen.

Comment: The site is [quantumcomputing.se], but if this is a homework question then please mind the remark by gIS and make sure any post there is on topic.

Comment: @Rasharashed I'd say it's more on-topic in https://physics.stackexchange.com... but it's also much more likely to be closed as homework-like there if written like it is here

Comment: @MaartenBodewes many thanks. This is not homework; I am trying to understand some concepts :)

Comment: The first part is very clearly differently written than your question. If you're quoting a source then please reference that source. That makes such a claim much easier to believe than it is now - I'm not saying that it is homework, but the question certainly *looks* like it...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, many thanks for you advice. Yes, this is good idea, I should write the reference.

Comment: You can still do that you know, if it's not a homework question. Just [edit] the question and comment below... if still applicable. Happy to reopen or migrate. I cannot promise answers of course...